# Saving the Updated Gridview row to my Database Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've added an edit/update option to a Gridview of bound data from a table in my database TextBooks. I'm allowing this in case something changes down the road the admin can then edit/update the information. Currently I am able to click edit type in the information, and then it binds it to the current Grid on page, but doesn't save it to the database and upon leaving the page and returning to it, it is reverted back to the old value. After following the code to the BindGrid() method i believe I've gone wrong somewhere but cannot fully grasp what it is I'm missing.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select  * from textBooks   ";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HUTDMSConnectionString"].ToString()))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))


                adapter.Fill(dt);
            ViewState["allBooks"] = dt;
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void BindGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["allBooks"] as DataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string Ancillary = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string BookActive = (row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;          
        string InactiveDate = (row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string Author = (row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string Publisher = (row.Cells[8].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string EditionAndDate = (row.Cells[9].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string Imprint = (row.Cells[10].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string eISBN = (row.Cells[13].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string ebookAvailable = (row.Cells[14].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string Notes = (row.Cells[15].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

        DataTable dt = ViewState["allBooks"] as DataTable;

        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Ancillary"] = Ancillary;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["BookActive"] = BookActive;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["InactiveDate"] = InactiveDate;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Author"] = Author;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Publisher"] = Publisher;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["EditionAndDate"] = EditionAndDate;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Imprint"] = Imprint;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["eISBN"] = eISBN;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ebookAvailable"] = ebookAvailable;
        dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Notes"] = Notes;


        ViewState["allBooks"] = dt;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you are currently doing is pulling data from a database, storing it in a gridview, then editing the data in the GridView. Once you call that databind command, that data becomes independent from the Database. In order to save this data to the database, I would recommend using SqlDataAdapter's [Update method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab5x5cd(v=vs.110).aspx) in the OnUpdate method. This will allow you to store the update values back to a datarow and save it to the database while following a similar strategy as when you fill the GridView.

Comment: im honestly lost on what i'm doing, just read through that page on the Update method and dont see how I incorporate that exactly with what I have